# Organizing UITableViewCell's by Creation Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, twitter, instagram

I have tweets and instagram pictures in two separate `NSDictionaries` , Currently I am just Aggregating the posts by making every other post a Tweet, and the latter a Instagram picture. How would I take these two and organize all the `UITableViewCell`'s and organize them by date?

I was thinking that I would return the `created_at` value from each and convert the string's to `NSDate`'s, but how would I do that for every single tweet and instapic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purpose you must create a new array with merging both tweets and instaPics array in single one then your all data sort as single piece.

Merge both data array as below::

```
NSArray *pictureArray = [tweets arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray: instaPics];
```

**Note ::** `NSDictionary (NSMutableDictionary)` is by default sorted according to its key value. Here we sort array according to particular key of contains dictionaries

Now sort your **pictureArray** as below::

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"created_at" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
pictureArray = [pictureArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Then redefine your tableview method as ::

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *tweetsCellIdentifier = @"tweetsCell";
    static NSString *instaCellIdentifier = @"instaCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    BOOL tweets = NO;

    // Now you get dictionary that may be of tweets array or instagram array 
    // Due to its different structure
    // I thinks your both dictionaries have different structure
    NSDictionary *pictDictionary = pictureArray[indexPath.row];
    if (your_check_condition for tweets dictionary) {
        tweets = YES;
    }

    // Get cell according to your dictionary data that may be from tweets or instagram
    if (tweets) {
       cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tweetsCellIdentifier];
    } else {
       cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:instaCellIdentifier];
    }

    if (cell == nil) {
      // Design your cell as you desired;
      if (tweets) {
        // Design cell for tweets
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tweetsCellIdentifier];
      } else {
        // Design cell for instagram
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:instaCellIdentifier];
      }

    }


     // Write your login to get dictionary picture data
     // Tweets and Instagram array are merged. So get appropriate data with your logic
     // May be both dictionaries structure are different. so write your logic to get picture data
      // Fill data according tweets dict or instgram
      // Get cell elements in which you will show dict data i.e. images, title etc.
      if (tweets) {
        // Fill cell data for tweets
      } else {
        // Fill cell data for instagram
      }

      return cell;
}
```

After all of above reload your tableview after getting data in pictureArray as below ..

```
//Reload TableView
[tableView reloadData];
```

It may help you.

**Editted ::**
Edit your code as below. I modify your instgram cell creations and filling. Like this define your tweets cell design and filling data as done for instagram

```
NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    static NSString *tweetsCellIdentifier = @"tweetsCell";
    static NSString *instaCellIdentifier = @"instaCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    BOOL tweets = YES;
    BOOL twitterLoggedIn = [user boolForKey:@"twitterLoggedIn"];

// Now you get dictionary that may be of tweets array or instagram array
// Due to its different structure
// I thinks your both dictionaries have different structure
NSDictionary *totalFeedDictionary = totalFeed[indexPath.row];

// Get cell according to your dictionary data that may be from tweets or instagram
if (tweets) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tweetsCellIdentifier];
} else {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:instaCellIdentifier];
}

if (cell == nil) {
    // Design your cell as you desired;
    if (tweets) {
        // Now correct it as instagram cell design below your tweets cell design
        // Only create here desired elements and its define design pattern here
        // Don't Fill here At last already we fill it 
        // Due to scrolling cells are reuse and must be fill all time when they come from deque cel
        // Design cell for tweets
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tweetsCellIdentifier];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];

        NSDictionary *tweet = totalFeed[indexPath.row];

        //Set username for twitter
        NSString *name = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];
        UILabel *twitterNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:202];
        [twitterNameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:12.0]];
        [twitterNameLabel setText:name];


        //Set status for twitter
        NSString *text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
        UILabel *twitterTweetLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:203];
        [twitterTweetLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:10.0]];
        [twitterTweetLabel setText:text];


        //Set Profile Pic for twitter
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSString *imageUrl = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UIImageView *profilePic = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:201];
                profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                //Make the Profile Pic ImageView Circular
                CALayer *imageLayer = profilePic.layer;
                [imageLayer setCornerRadius:25];
                [imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
            });
        });


        //Set number of Favorites for Tweet
        NSString *favoritesCount = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"]objectForKey:@"favourites_count"];
        UIButton *favoritesButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:204];
        [favoritesButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@",favoritesCount] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [favoritesButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@",favoritesCount] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        favoritesButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:12];

    } else {
        // Design cell for instagram
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:instaCellIdentifier];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];

        UIImageView *instagramImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        instagramImageView.tag = 104;
         [cell.contentView addSubview:instagramImageView];

        UILabel *instagramUserLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        instagramUserLabel.tag = 102;
        [instagramUserLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:16.0]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:instagramUserLabel];

        UILabel *instagramCaptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            [instagramCaptionLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:12.0]];
        instagramCaptionLabel.tag = 103;
         [cell.contentView addSubview:instagramCaptionLabel];

        UIImageView *instagramProfilePic = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        instagramProfilePic.frame = CGRectMake(35, 31, 50, 50);
        instagramProfilePic.tag = 101;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:instagramProfilePic];
    }

}

// Fill Data here
if (tweets) {
     // Now correct as below your tweets cell filling
     // Only get here desired elements and fill them here
} else {
     NSDictionary *entry = totalFeed[indexPath.row];

     NSString *imageUrlString = entry[@"images"][@"low_resolution"][@"url"];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString];
        UIImageView *instagramImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:104];
        [instagramImageView setImageWithURL:url];

        NSString *user =  entry[@"user"][@"full_name"];
        UILabel *instagramUserLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
        [instagramUserLabel setText:user];

     UILabel *instagramCaptionLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
     if (entry[@"caption"] != [NSNull null] && entry[@"caption"][@"text"] != [NSNull null])            {
            NSString *caption = entry[@"caption"][@"text"];
            [instagramCaptionLabel setText:caption];
        }else{
            NSString *caption = @"";
            [instagramCaptionLabel setText:caption];

        }

     NSString *imageUserPicUrl = entry[@"user"][@"profile_pic"][@"url"];
     NSURL *profileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUserPicUrl];
     UIImageView *instagramProfilePic = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
     [instagramProfilePic setImageWithURL:profileURL];
}

return cell;
```

Comment: However I have two different types of cell, one for Twitter Cell's and One for the Instagram Cell, how would I order the two cells?

Comment: @prnk28 see this editted answer. if you get any problem, just comment. waiting!!!

Comment: @Nour1991 I have entered all my data and my uitableview now displays nothing at all and crashes. I have edited the question to show how I have done it. Here is the Error: `CRASH :
 UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: @prnk28 in your `if(tweets)` you are setting the cell value twice, after you say `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tweetsCellIdentifier];` you are saying : `cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tweetsCellIdentifier];` so remove the second line and see how it goes !!
coz the error you are getting indicates that your cell is coming back nil, which is messing up the `UITableView`

Comment: it still gives me the same issue

Comment: Not displaying instagram is not what i wanted. I wanted to display both instapics and tweets simultaneously arranged by date.

Comment: @LalitKumar I have realized why the posts are not displaying. this is due to the fact that the Instagram Pics and Twitter tweets have different keys for creation. For Instagram it is `creation_time` and it is using a unix timestamp. As for twitter it uses the `created_at` and uses a normal timestamp.

Comment: @prnk28 In my answer and in comment I asked for your both dictionary structures. As already discuss in my answer these dictionaries play main role in your decision making and ask different approach on its self (each dictionaries).

Answer (score 2):

You have to sort **tweets** and **instaPics** arrays with **creation_date** before cellForRowAtIndexPath is called. Write this code in viewDidLoad then reload the tableView.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"created_at" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
tweets = [tweets sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
instaPics = [instaPics sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
//Reload TableView
[tableView reloadData];
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Well both the arrays i am using are NSMutableDictionaries so the method did not work, and also what would I do in the beginning of the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method after I sort the arrays. How would I replace the top `if()else()` statement?

Comment: The call to [tableView reloadData] would reload the table after ordering your dictionaries. Dictionaries are not sortable. You can, however, sort the keys or values of the dictionary by creating arrays for keys/values from dictionary.allKeys or dictionary.allValues and then sort and repopulate the dictionary.

Comment: @prnk28 Chris comment is absolutely right, you need to sort dictionary keys and then use those to create tableView cells like this.    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { //...Your code...// NSDictionary *tweet = tweets[tweets.allKeys[indexPath.row]]; //...Your code...// } Regarding your if()else() statement, I dont understand what you want to do exactly. Please clearify

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.tweets sortUsingComparator:^(Tweet *a, Tweet *b){
    return [b.dateCreated compare:a.dateCreated];
}];
```